# Big difference between validation and test results- machine learning regression task

Tags: python, machine-learning

I'm building a machine learning model for predicting apartment prices. The data is divided into 3 parts:

train and validation

(includes over 80k past transactions in one city)

Test

(includes about 1000 new transactions in the market)

The data of past transactions is divided between the years 2005-2023.
The data includes about 20 different features.

you can assuming that the data is clean, after feature engineering and cleaning of outliers.

I used all the techniques of ML and I get good results in the first part on all the models with avg r2_score of 0.8 .

However, on the test data I get very bad results for all models:
CatBoostRegressor

r2_score: -0.45392244082305133
mae: 1586571

XGBRegressor

r2_score: -0.49411544410762476
mae: 1614740

RandomForestRegressor

r2_score: -0.35392521366085083
mae: 1533444

Linear Regression

r2_score: -0.8979850713342505
mae: 1848273

Polynomial Regression

r2_score: -4.506854656472743e+19
mae: 10908520455089478

stacking

r2_score: -2.90848287219759e+16
mae: 258422584512952

The code is very long so I will only attach the more important parts:

```
models_list = {
         'CatBoostRegressor': CatBoostRegressor(logging_level='Silent'),
         'XGBRegressor': XGBRegressor(logging_level='Silent'),
         'RandomForestRegressor': RandomForestRegressor(),
         'LinearRegression': LinearRegression(),
         'PolynomialRegression': Pipeline([('PolynomialFeatures', PolynomialFeatures()),
                                                  ('LinearRegression', LinearRegression())])}


best_params = {
   'RandomForestRegressor': {'bootstrap': False, 'max_depth': 15, 'max_features': 'sqrt', 'min_samples_leaf': 2, 'min_samples_split': 5, 'n_estimators': 200},
    'CatBoostRegressor': {'depth': 10, 'iterations': 1500, 'l2_leaf_reg': 9, 'learning_rate': 0.05},
    'XGBRegressor':{'learning_rate': 0.07, 'max_depth': 5, 'n_estimators': 150},
    'LinearRegression': {'fit_intercept': True, 'normalize': True},
    'PolynomialFeatures': {'degree': 4, 'include_bias': True, 'interaction_only': True}

}
def get_stacking(params):
    level0 = []
    level0.append(('CatBoostRegressor', CatBoostRegressor(**params['CatBoostRegressor'], logging_level='Silent'))) 
    level0.append(('RandomForestRegressor', RandomForestRegressor(**params['RandomForestRegressor'])))
    level0.append(('XGBRegressor', XGBRegressor(**params['XGBRegressor'], logging_level='Silent')))
    level0.append(('LinearRegression', LinearRegression(**params['LinearRegression'])))
    level0.append(('PolynomialRegression', Pipeline([('PolynomialFeatures', PolynomialFeatures(**best_params['PolynomialFeatures'])),
           ('LinearRegression', LinearRegression(**best_params['LinearRegression']))])))

    level1 =  Pipeline([('PolynomialFeatures', PolynomialFeatures(**best_params['PolynomialFeatures'])),
           ('LinearRegression', LinearRegression(**best_params['LinearRegression']))])
    model = StackingRegressor(estimators=level0, final_estimator=level1, cv=5)
    return model
 
def find_best_params(models , X_train_selected ,y_train ):
    best_params = {}
    
    for name, model in models.items():
        print("Tuning", name)
        clf = GridSearchCV(model, params[name], cv=5, n_jobs=-1)
        clf.fit(X_train_selected, y_train)
        best_params[name] = clf.best_params_
        print("Best parameters:", best_params[name])
        
    return best_params
 
    
def evaluate_model(model,X_train_scaled, X_test_scaled  ,y_train, y_test):
    
    model_train = model.fit(X_train_scaled , y_train)
    cv = RepeatedKFold(n_splits=5, n_repeats=3, random_state=42)
    results_score = cross_val_score(model_train, X_test_scaled, y_test, scoring='neg_mean_absolute_error', cv=cv, n_jobs=-1  )

    y_pred = model_train.predict(X_test_scaled)
        
    r2 = r2_score(y_test, y_pred)
    mae_score = mean_absolute_error(y_test, y_pred)

    return {
        'accuracy': {'mean': mean(results_score), 'std': std(results_score)},
        'r2_score': r2,
        'mae_score': mae_score,
        'results_score': results_score,
        'y_pred': y_pred,
        'model': model_train
    }

def predict_test_data(df, scores):
    y = df['Price']
    X = df.drop('Price', axis=1)
    scaler = MinMaxScaler()
    X_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(X)
    df_predict_dict = {}
    
    for model_name, model_scores in scores.items():
        y_pred = scores[model_name]['model'].predict(X_scaled)
        mae = mean_absolute_error(y, y_pred)
        r2 = r2_score(y, y_pred)
        print(f'{model_name}\nr2_score: {r2} , mae: {int(mae)}\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are getting good results in the Validating data but bad results in the Testing data. This usually means that your model is overfitted. This usually happens for many reasons including the features you are using (maybe some of them are unuseful or not helping the model) or you could change the value of some of the hyperparameters.

You can try the correlation between the features and the target feature and then exclude the unneeded ones. Also, you can check your data for any outliers in the data that could influence the linear line.